# Are mobile hotspots generated by your iPhone or Android device ad hoc or "regular"?

Tags: android, iphone, adhoc

Haven't been able to find much data on this by googling around, so maybe someone can tell me definitively? I remember reading that generating wifi from older android phones (like my Droid 1) is an ad hoc network, but a lot of newer phones are released intended to be used as a mobile hotspot, are these running in ad hoc mode as well?

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy SII provides a WiFi access point when I use it as a WiFi hotspot. My old HTC Magic (Nordic version) provides an ad hoc network. I only have information about these two smartphones to share but I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about what exactly you're asking the answer is that practically speaking it doesn't matter. The differences between ad-hoc and infrastructure networks really only come into play when you're dealing with more than two nodes. I haven't tested it but I don't even know that iPhone or Android hotspots allow you to communicate with other clients connected to the hotspot. It's primary purpose is to serve internet and as a gesture to security in public places they might have simply just disabled client to client connections. Essentially, each connection becomes it's own two node network.

Answer (score 1):

Android's stock hotspot feature uses infrastructure mode, not ad-hoc.